# IPv4 address search using regular expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex

I am trying to sanitize a configuration file in notepad++.
Basically, I need to find and replace the IPv4 address with regular expression and replace only first two octet, I tried with following regular expression to search for IPV4, however didnt work in notepad++

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(?1)){3}\b
```

Could anyone please help ?

Comment: Posting some examples would fetch you better answers here

Comment: For example I want search IPV4 address in the config file, and then replaced only first two octets with X.X
so 192.168.1.2 address will be replaced with X.X.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex [`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(?1)){3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ZoWIWp/1) captures the first octet in group 1, then matches the 2nd and 3rd octet and captures the fourth octet in group 2.

To replace the first 2 octets you want to match the first 2 octets and capture the last 2 octets to keep them in the replacement.

What you could do it to match all 4 octects using `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)` for an octet and capture the last 2 including the leading dot for the third octet and the replace with X.X followed by capturing group 1.

**Find**

[`\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/DBV9py/1)

**Replace with**

`X.X\1`